# CSS grid with filter function not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, css-grid

I am trying to make a filter function with jQuery for my gallery.

When a button is pressed the images gets filtered by a category.

I've used jQuery to `add` and `remove` a class so I can move the images to fit into the right row as they move when a button is pressed.

But the problem is that the `add` class is always shown.

For example, when the `btn-1` is pressed `grid-item-6` should move from row nr. 4 to row nr. 1 - but instead of moving it just stays at row nr. 1 all the time. 
*(When I say move, not move as an animation - just move the position)*

[Grid-item-6 at row 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1mZi.png)

Another problem is when I press `btn-1` the first time the gallery is properly shown, but the second time I press the button the elements disappears.

[First press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhmvQ.png)

[Second press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8wAL.png)

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#btnContainer button").each(function() {
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            var filtertag = $(this).attr('class');
            $('.grid-item').show();
            $('.grid-item:not(.' + filtertag + ')').hide();
        });
    });

    $('.btn-1').on("click", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("grid-item-6");
         $(this).addClass("grid-item-6-2");
          return false;
     });

});

<div class="container"  id="grid-container">

    <div id="btnContainer">
            <button class="btn-all">All</button>
            <button class="btn-1">btn1</button>
        </div>

<div class="row">

        <div class="grid-wrapper">
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-1 btn-all">1</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-2 btn-all">2</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-3 btn-all">3</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-4 btn-all">4</div>

                <div class="grid-item grid-item-5 btn-all">5</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-6 grid-item-6-2 btn-all btn-1">6</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-7 btn-all">7</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-8 grid-item-8-2 btn-all btn-1">8</div>

                <div class="grid-item grid-item-9 btn-all">9</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-10 grid-item-10-2 btn-all btn-1">10</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-11 grid-item-11-2 btn-all btn-1">11</div>
            </div>

</div>
```

```
    .grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 250px 250px 250px 250px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    grid-gap: 3rem;
}

.grid-item-1 {
    background: grey;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.grid-item-2 {
    background: lightgrey;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
}

.grid-item-3 {
    background: lightblue;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.grid-item-4 {
    background: lightsalmon;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
}

.grid-item-5 {
    background: lightskyblue;
    grid-row: 3 / span 3;
}

.grid-item-6 {
    background: lightslategray;
    grid-row: 4 / span 3;
}

.grid-item-6-2 {
    background: lightslategray;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly better way to do this - you can use a dynamic loop if you have lots of buttons, but for just a few this would work fine.

```js
  $( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#btn-all').on("click", function() {
         $('.grid-item').show();
     });

    $('#btn-1').on("click", function() {
          $('.grid-item').hide();
          $('.btn-1').show();
     });

});
```

```css
  .grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 250px 250px 250px 250px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    grid-gap: 3rem;
}

.grid-item-1 {
    background: grey;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.grid-item-2 {
    background: lightgrey;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
}

.grid-item-3 {
    background: lightblue;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.grid-item-4 {
    background: lightsalmon;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
}

.grid-item-5 {
    background: lightskyblue;
    grid-row: 3 / span 3;
}

.grid-item-6 {
    background: lightslategray;
    grid-row: 4 / span 3;
}

.grid-item-6-2 {
    background: lightslategray;
    grid-row: 1 / span 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"  id="grid-container">

    <div id="btnContainer">
            <button id="btn-all">All</button>
            <button id="btn-1">btn1</button>
        </div>

<div class="row">

        <div class="grid-wrapper">
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-1 btn-all">1</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-2 btn-all">2</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-3 btn-all">3</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-4 btn-all">4</div>

                <div class="grid-item grid-item-5 btn-all">5</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-6 grid-item-6-2 btn-all btn-1">6</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-7 btn-all">7</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-8 grid-item-8-2 btn-all btn-1">8</div>

                <div class="grid-item grid-item-9 btn-all">9</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-10 grid-item-10-2 btn-all btn-1">10</div>
                <div class="grid-item grid-item-11 grid-item-11-2 btn-all btn-1">11</div>
            </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Awesome!